# Using the Proof of Reserves utility developed by blockstream

Tags: proof-of-solvency

I was looking into the various methods that can be used to generate the proof of reserves and came across the open source version created by blockstream to generate the proof of reserves( https://github.com/ElementsProject/reserves ).

However I am unable to use the utility as is and need some guidance on how to use it. According to my little understanding I may have to install a few softwares in order to run the utility. Can someone help me out? Pardon me if it is a stupid mistake/question as I am very new to bitcoin and am at a very very basic level.